Prepros - How to recompile entire project?
I am wondering if anyone knows how can you tell Prepros program to recompile all your sass files in your project?
I have tried the "Refresh Project" option when you right click on your project inside the program and that does not do it. I have also tried to Disable File watcher and enable it again, that also did not do it.
Is there a way to do this? I know I can right click on individual file and click "Process" which will compile it, but I have over a 100 sass files in my project and this is unrealistic.
Consider the scenario of another team member updating some sass files and then committing them to your repository. When I download them I need to compile them. However, I may not know which all files need to be compiled so I want the project to recompile them all to ensure nothing was missed. Going file by file is too tedious. Is there a way?
